# Java - Socket - Freeze

Tags: java, sockets, freeze

i've a minimal server which wait until a client connect ,then he start a thread which will send a reply back to the client, the problem is the reply.

This is the code of the server:

```
 int port = 1234;
 ServerSocket servSock = null;
 servSock = new ServerSocket(port);       
  while (true) {
   Socket link = servSock.accept();
   serverThread st = new serverThread(link);
   st.start();
  }
```

This is the code of the run() method of the thread,the one which send the answer back, sk is the socket "link" passed by parameter in the server code

```
 public void run() {
    String dato = "";
    InputStream i = null;
    try {
        i = sk.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(serverThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
        Scanner input = new Scanner(i);
     //i receive the data sent
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            dato += input.nextLine();
        }   
    // then i send a reply
    DataOutputStream outputStream=new DataOutputStream(sk.getOutputStream());
    outputStream.writeInt(1);
    outputStream.close();
```

Client side ( only the code which should receive the answer from the server) :

```
        Socket link;
        int valid = 0;
        String url="localhost";
        int port=1234;
        link = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(url), port);

        //i've to send some data to the server
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(link.getOutputStream(), true);
        String a = new String(Base64.encode(mex));
        output.println(createXml(tag, a));
        output.flush();


        //then i need to receive an answer from the server
        DataInputStream answerI = new DataInputStream(link.getInputStream());

        while(answerI.available()!=0)// but answerI.available() is always equal 0
           valid = answerI.readInt();

        answerI.close();
        output.close (); 
        link.close();
```

With this code the istruction    valid = answerI.readInt();  is not reached.

Without the while cycle, the client freeze at line :  valid = answerI.readInt();

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Possible duplicate: "shrimp - heaven - now".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that the server is blocked in a call to `input.hasNext()`. This will return false when the socket is closed, and its `InputStream` returns -1 to signal the end of the stream. However, the socket is still open. The client *can* send another line; the `Scanner` is blocking to see what the client's next move will be.

There are ways to shutdown "half" of a socket, so that the server can tell that the client has closed its sending channel but can still receive a response.

However, this approach is complicated. I suggest a change to the protocol so that the server can determine when it is allowed to respond.

Answer (score 0):

In this protocol you don't need the reply if it is always '1'. Just close the socket. The client should block in a read() which will return -1 when the server closes the socket.

Comment: the reply will not be always 1, i've put 1 to test the protocol, currently i close the input stream and the output stream separately in the server and in the client, for  example:

1 - client send mex to server then  closes the output stream

2 - server receive the mex then closes the inputstream,

3 - server open an outputstream and the client open an inputstream

4 - server send the reply back to the client.

Now it works :) thank you!